QTableWidget: не окрашиваются строки при выделении selectRow(i)
В таблице с выделением строк по сочетанию клавиш Key_Home и Shift хочу выделить строки с текущей вверх - по нулевую. Выделение происходит, как показывают дальнейшие действия, но на экране это выделение не отображается, как обычно при выделении строк вручную по одной. Фрагменты кода:
//--------------------------------------------------
//  mainwindow.h
...
class MainWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
 
 protected:
   bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event);
...
}
 
//--------------------------------------------------
//  mainwindow.cpp
 
...
 
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
...
    ui->table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui->table->installEventFilter(this);
...
}
 
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if (!ui->table->hasFocus()) return false;
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
      QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
      if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Home && (keyEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) && ui->table->currentRow() >= 0)
      {
        for (int i = ui->table->currentRow(); i >= 0; --i)
        {
          ui->table->selectRow(i);
        }
        ui->table->setCurrentCell(0, 0);
      }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}

Как окрасить строки при использовании функции selectRow(i)?
...
Вопрос решён, благодаря needKVAS, см. комментарии.

А вручную через selectionModel пробовали выделять? Например: ui->table->selectionModel()->select(ui->table->model()->index(i,0), QItemSelectionModel::Select |  QItemSelectionModel::Rows);

Вручную выделяется без проблем - по одной вверх и вниз (Key_Up (или Key_Down)+Shift. Если программно выделять каждый индекс, то выделение отображается на экране, но потом, при переходе к ручному выделению и развыделению строки на экране остаются окрашенными.

Я вообще имел ввиду ввиду что не использовать selectRow, а то что я написал. И теперь я не совсем понял в чём заключается проблема. Строки не выделяются или остаются выделенными когда не должны? И какой у вас selectionMode?

А вот так: ui->table->selectionModel()->select(QItemSelection(ui->table->model()->index(0,0),ui->table->selectionModel()->currentIndex()), QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent |  QItemSelectionModel::Rows); (Вместо всего for)

needKVAS, много вариантов перепробовал, включая ваш. Если поставить ваш код вместо цикла, оставив ui->table->setCurrentCell(0, 0) после него (мне и нужно, чтобы текущей стала нулевая строка), то ничего не меняется по сравнению с моим кодом - строки выделяются но на экране они остаются неокрашенными. Если setCurrentCell(0, 0) убираем, т.е. текущей остаётся последняя выделенная строка, то выделение отображается цветом, но при попытке сразу же перейти на ручное выделение , например,  Key_Down+Shift, выделение пропадает.

needKVAS: "И какой у вас selectionMode?"
Перепробовал все, но вообще нужно SingleSelection (по умолчанию)
needKVAS: "не совсем понял в чём заключается проблема"
Я первый раз на этом форуме, может привести картинки тестового примера таблицы? можно в комментарий вставить картинку, как это сделать?

Вместо setCurrentCell(0, 0) попробуйте ui->table->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(ui->table->model()->index(0,0), QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);. Со вторым вариантом у меня корректно работает Key_Down+Shift

Если вам нужно добавить пояснительную картинку, вы должны отредактировать вопрос, нажав кнопочку править. SingleSelection позволит вам выделить одновременно только одну строку. Вы уверены что он вам нужен? И мне кажется, что это не мод по умолчанию.

needKVAS, большое спасибо. Так работает в обе стороны нужным образом). Добавил ещё реакцию на Key_End и вставил в свой класс на основе QTableWidget.Надо сказать, что на Qt тоже начал программировать совсем недавно ( до этого много лет на билдере).

SingleSelection по умолчанию, видимо, стоит ExtendedSelection - с ним работает тоже как надо.
